# Can we show value of uncontrolled input in real time?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

we all know that uncontrolled inputs might come handy in forms to submit values on `onSubmit` event.

but I was wondering can we do such thing :

```js
const MyComponent =()=>{
 const[state,setState] = useState();
 const HandleChange =(event)=>{
  setState(event.target.value);
 }
 return(
  <div>
    <input type='text' onChange={HandleChange} value={state}/>
    <p>{state}</p>
  </div>
)
}
```

as you can see, we can get the real time value of the input inside of `p` tag. which is obvious.

but I was wondering, can we create similar situation with uncontrolled input and the `Ref` ?

is this possible or we always need to have an event to show values, since there's no re render?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can we create similar situation with uncontrolled input and the `Ref` ?

You can [manipulate the DOM using a ref](https://react.dev/reference/react/useRef#manipulating-the-dom-with-a-ref) (but it's not idiomatic React to do so):

[Code in TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBDAnmApnA3nAwgCwIYB2A5igKIBuKB8AvnAGZQQhwBEUKeAxjKwNwAoAaEiwMcLhzwwUAJQgRaDJi3aceAWgAmzAPRcANsCq9BI6PEwBlGFGA8AshC0oANHACuAZzkp6cOkZmNikefiF6DwIeYAgCOABBMDAACgBKDAE4CTiveDA8KDwiIrAcWT84AF5PHwr6AB4ACQAVBwAZAAVC4tKcUgMUEBMAPhSCDwMDNMEsnII8zzAtaRRuopK8MpaUAA94GpS57JRyAC5sfGIySmpmtvaASQIwDxgBodHXOYyqkbgChs+vUAHRcDxQDjUACEIJk+ywcRk1GqcFOYIhUJgLUKJBgIPIeAMHhQs2yHBgEPiR2y2QaWmA5BGx1pDWALzeLNpCGQKCqrHhvC5tLiuEIJCq6A8y1W616WxwO32NGF2TABm4KBwEAMLig-JavLgOBQHFYwt0zO5dLAcA49ElgPlZXqNBGDV0YCtrN0DKZP0EKoEkk4MnkihSOnBw2oILxHxjMAAQohHloUuwFLw0tC0iCoXqaXAGjY7I5nChvXSkrbLXMPaX7DAnC4Rt8ZgIgA)

```html
<div id="root"></div><script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react@18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script><script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react-dom@18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script><script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@babel/standalone@7.22.13/babel.min.js"></script><script>Babel.registerPreset("tsx", {presets: [[Babel.availablePresets["typescript"], {allExtensions: true, isTSX: true}]]});</script>
<script type="text/babel" data-type="module" data-presets="tsx,react">

import type { ChangeEvent } from "react";

// This Stack Overflow snippet demo uses UMD modules
const { createRoot } = ReactDOM;
const { StrictMode, useRef } = React;

function App() {
  const paragraphRef = useRef<HTMLParagraphElement>(null);

  const updateParagraphText = (
    ev: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>,
  ) => paragraphRef.current!.textContent = ev.currentTarget.value;

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        onChange={updateParagraphText}
        placeholder="Type here"
      />
      <p ref={paragraphRef}></p>
    </div>
  );
}

createRoot(document.getElementById("root")!).render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>,
);

</script>
```

Comment: thank for answer. btw `paragraphRef.current!.textContent` there's an exclamation mark. I think is a typo.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77001458/can-we-show-value-of-uncontrolled-input-in-real-time/77001639#comment135745359_77001639) @user16069077 It’s the [Non-null Assertion Operator (Postfix `!`)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#non-null-assertion-operator-postfix-) in TypeScript. That entire code block is TypeScript, but you can see the compiled JS at the playground link in the panel on the right.